# Bike chain too long?

Tags: chain

Recently, my road bike's chain got cut, so i took it for replacement. A new chain was inserted and the shifting had a good transition. However, when i shift on the harder gears, i hear "crack crack noises" as if the chain is not well fit. I returned it to the repairman who still said he now fixed the problem but i still have the same issues. It seems he only tested the bike while suspended but not on actual ground. Is this because the new chain was too long ?

Comment: To answer your specific question, the chain length can be calculated, and whether or not the bike is in a stand should make no difference. It would be helpful here if you knew what the repairman had tweaked in order for him to say he'd fixed the problem

Comment: @PeteH Length may be the same on the stand or not.  But force is factor on chain jump on a worn cog.

Comment: As @Blam points out, your cassette is most likely worn. The venerable Sheldon Brown has a [wonderful article](http://sheldonbrown.com/chains.html#stretch) about how chains and rear cogs wear together and then everything goes to pot when you replace the chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need a new cassette/freewheel. A new chain on a worn cassette will jump (especially on the harder gears).

The harder gears have two things going against them. 
Less points of contact to share the load. 
Less points of contact so they tend to be worn the most.

If you have front derailleur then using the bigger ring there will let you use bigger cogs in the rear.  If I can be in 3 or higher in the rear on the big ring up front then I use the big ring up front to keep miles off the smaller cogs in back.

Comment: Can replacement be avoided by adjusting the bike shift to only 1 speed ? I am not financially sound now.

Comment: On the cassette/freewheel different cogs will be worn to different extents.  If you stay on the less worn you will get less (or no) skipping.  And once the new chain stretches it might start working on the harder gears.  Save up and next time get a chain and cassette.

Comment: If you keep riding, the new chain will rapidly wear down to match the wear on the cassette/freewheel.